# What are my options in terms of posting on a user's friend's wall, on behalf of either the user or my app?

Tags: facebook

I have an app that a user signs up for that needs to then notify a friend of said user about an upcoming event.

I'm trying to figure out what my options are for how to make this work.  In an ideal world, my app would would be able to post to the friend's wall with a custom message (written by the user) at some predetermined time in the future. However, I'm not seeing anything in the API for posting on behalf of a user to one of their friend's walls, so, I'm open to suggestion.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post to a user's friend's feed using the Graph API, assuming the user granted you the relevant (publish_stream) permissions.

```
POST /[friend]/feed

message=hello...
```

Users generally consider this very spammy behavior for apps, and so it is not particularly recommended.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/